# Is it a bad practice to mix query and body params in POST request?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, web

It's a just curiosity. If it's really bad practice to mix query and body params in POST request.

Just for example:

/someservice/create/{id}?idApp=989898

RequestBody: {par1: par1, par2: par2}

Comment: It's not. URL identifies *something* you want. You could do `GET /users?id=42` to receive the user with this ID or `PATCH /users?id=42` to update the user with whatever is in the body of this request. That's valid and *preferred* in many cases, since you're dealing with the same user identified by `/users?id=42`, you then do GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE to manipulate that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oversimplifying, the URI is there to identify the resource and the request body is there so you can send information with the request. So for instance:

```
POST /modify/whatsit?id=123
Body: Data for modifying the whatsit
```

is fine. The URI is saying what to modify (whatsit 123), and the body is the information for that.

Your example uses `create` in the URI, so I wouldn't expect it to also have an `idApp` parameter, since IDs are normally assigned as/when the item is created. So in that particular example, I wouldn't expect to find query parameters in the URI. I'd normally expect any additional information for the `create` operation to be in the request body.

That said, sometimes people put the identifying information in the request body instead. One advantage to having it in the URI is that logs containing the URI but not the post body tell you not just *that* a resource was modified (`/modify/whatsit`), but *which* resource was modified (`/modify/whatsit?id=123`).